# Find target in sorted array pivoted at some unknown point in O(log n)

Tags: javascript, array, complexity, binary-search, namespaces

> You are given an array sorted in ascending order which is rotated at
>   some pivot unknown to you beforehand. Find your target in \$O(log n)\$
>   which means it should be a binary search. If the value does not exist
>   return `-1`.

The approach I took was to narrow the subset of solutions by using an upper bound `infinity` and a lower bound `infinity`. I would cut the array in half. If the `mid` was less than the `target`, the right of the `mid` would become the new lower bound and if the `high` was less than the current `target` the `mid` would be the new upper bound.

```js
function findTarget(array, target) {
  let lo = 0,
    hi = array.length,
    limit;
  while (lo < hi) {
  let mid=Math.floor((hi+lo)/2);
    if ((array[mid] < array[0]) === (target < array[0])) {
      limit = array[mid]
    } else if (target < array[0]) {
      limit = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY
    } else {
      limit = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY
    }
    if (limit < target) {
      lo = mid + 1
    } else if (limit > target) {
      hi = mid
    } else {
      return mid
    }
  }
  return -1
}


console.log(findTarget([4, 5, 6, 7, 0, 1, 2], 3))
```